# Formatting lost when updating jqGrid row

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I display a jqGrid table of recipes and provide a master-details type view for the user.  When the user selects a recipe from the grid, it displays the details of that recipe in a div below the grid.  Then, I provide an in-place editing capability inside that div.  When the user saves the edits, I redisplay the details to the recipe.  That all works well enough.  Now, the selected grid row may have data which doesn't match what the details show after the update, so I do something like this to update the grid:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   data: "id=" recipeId,
   url:  '@Url.Action("GetGridDataForRecipe", "Recipe")',
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (result) {
      var myGrid = $("#recipeGrid");
      var selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
      myGrid.jqGrid('setRowData', selRowId, result);
   }
});
```

My controller action looks like so:

```
public JsonResult GetGridDataForRecipe(int id)
{
   // ...
   var recipeData = context.recipes.Where(m => m.RecipeId == id).Select(row => new
   {
      RecipeId = row.RecipeId,
      RecipeName = row.RecipeName,
      RecipeDate = row.RecipeDate,
   }).First();
   return Json(recipeData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

So, the update works almost perfectly with the exception that the RecipeDate entry ends up getting displayed like so:

```
/Date(1317182400000)/
```

rather than the formatted date:

```
10/03/2011
```

that I specified in the `colModel` when I return the grid rows:

```
{ name: 'RecipeDate', index: 'RecipeDate', width: 120, align: 'left', sorttype: 'date',
   formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm/d/Y'},
...
```

There's a disconnect here between the `colModel` that I specified when the grid is displayed and the data I'm updating later.  Do I need to re-specify this information?  How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to re-specify this information?

Yes.

> How do I do that?

You could perform this formatting in the anonymous object your are returning from your controller action:

```
var recipeData = context.recipes.Where(m => m.RecipeId == id).Select(row => new
{
    RecipeId = row.RecipeId,
    RecipeName = row.RecipeName,
    RecipeDate = row.RecipeDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
}).First();
```

Comment: Thanks Darin - now, that was much simpler than I was envisioning.  Works great.

Comment: This answer requires one to duplicate the formatting code on the server side, which is far less than ideal. I'm gonna keep looking.

Answer (score 0):

Found an [answer on GitHub](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/issues/5).

> Adding $.jgrid.formatter.date.reformatAfterEdit = true; before I call setRowData seems to be a good work around for now.

I added this code and my dates now come out formatted as I expect.